# Abusive suggested edit by an anonymous user

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, abuse

If there is some abusing suggestion from anonymous user, is there a way to take some action against that? or some kind of penalty?

[image]

[from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20795862)

Comment: If an edit is spam/vandalism, mark it as such so the system/moderators can track it. That said, anonymous user suggestions are pretty drive-by.

Comment: what will happan when the user is anonymous,  can moderator do the same in that case?

Comment: if the user is anonymous it's fairly likely they will have not invested much time/effort and would not miss the destruction of their account much. The automatic systems might well ban their IP address at some point though.

Comment: that's unusual, all the vandalism I ever get are tests...

Comment: this one was real, i also thought of it as one of the test.

Comment: Every single forum on internet is subjet to trolls and those kinds of abuses. Just reject it as such and move on. Being an anonymous user he won't care anyway.

Comment: I'm surprised to learn Stack Exchange even allows edit suggestions by anonymous users!

Comment: Who are these anonymous users exactly?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Reject as spam/vandalism. *Do not* use a custom message as you appear to have done; not only is it a waste of keystrokes given that this is an anonymous user (also most abusive users aren't going to listen to you anyway), but rejecting as spam/vandalism as opposed to using a custom message will also cause the edit and the originating IP to be fed into the system to train it to detect and block further abuse.

Answer (score 46):

There is a reject reason to mark *spam or vandalism* edits:

[image]

Just select this as your reject reason whenever you find edits like these. This will get picked up by the system and the mods will go after them.